# record serialization and desirialization in JavaFX

Tags: maven, javafx, java-17

I have a maven No-modular javaFX application and I have this Java 17 record:

```
public record Item(

        @JsonProperty("visit")
        SimpleIntegerProperty visit,

        @JsonProperty("tdo")
        SimpleStringProperty tdo,

        @JsonProperty("id")
        SimpleStringProperty id,

        @JsonProperty("name")
        SimpleStringProperty name
) {
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty.bean accessible: module javafx.base does not "opens javafx.beans.property" to unnamed module @16a01b7

Comment: Your serialization framework is trying to serialize the property objects themselves (e.g., the `SimpleIntegerProperty` rather than the `int` said property wraps). That means the framework is trying to use reflection on those properties, but they are part of the `javafx.base` module, which does not `opens` their package to reflection. Most likely you don't want to serialize the property objects, but rather their values. I would look into if your framework allows you to customize how things are serialized. Also, I'm not sure JavaFX properties and `record`s really go together, conceptually.

Comment: The error occurs because your package cannot reflectively access the fields of `SimoleStringProperty`. It doesn’t really make a lot of sense to do this anyway; you want to serialise the underlying values, not the `Property` instances themselves.

Comment: Please do not use all caps.

Comment: And your application does not seem to be so non-modular as you think.

Comment: record the variable that each property has , not  the property itself , like so : int visit = visit.get()